# uibutton setframe not working no auto layaout enabled

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, cgrectmake

I have an uibutton which i want to change its position depending on the device however this code:

```
[self.notification setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 495, 17, 18)];
```

does not work at all! No auto layout enabled. Any thoughts?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@", self.notification)` at that same point in your program. I'm betting it's nil.

Comment: i get this one: <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x1dd7fe90; frame = (12 495; 17 18); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0x1dd7f390>>

Comment: So your code is working perfectly! It has exactly the frame you said!

Comment: So why it is not moving!!!!

Comment: Because it is already there!

Comment: hmmm nop i changed the 495 to 650 but stays at the same place!!!

Comment: Prove it. Log it before the `setFrame:` and after the `setFrame:` and see if the frame changed.

Comment: If it works, then you must have some *other* code you are not telling me about that *also* sets the frame (back to where it was). Remember, if you say setFrame:frameA and setFrame:frameB, you will *never* see frameA, only frameB - the *last* frame you set it to.

Comment: the proof2013-05-05 03:03:36.184 :c07] before <UIRoundedRectButton: 0xbe66830; frame = (4 407; 17 18); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0xbe65d50>>
2013-05-05 03:03:36.185 :c07] after <UIRoundedRectButton: 0xbe66830; frame = (12 550; 17 18); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 10; layer = <CALayer: 0xbe65d50>>

Comment: Solved it. Isn't logging wonderful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the button you are moving, `self.notification` is invisible; you have set its `hidden` to YES. So it is moving, but you cannot see it move, because you cannot see it at all. Perhaps it is not the button you think it is!

Comment: This has happened to everyone. :)